# Django-CSRF: CSRF verification failed. Request aborted when click on login button

Tags: django, django-csrf

I am trying to build a simple website where one can add data into MySQL database. I have a POST form with two text input(username, password). I have read all the related answer and tried to solve it but could not succeed.

index.html

```
<form action="/login/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}<table border="0" cellspacing="15" width="345" align="center">
<tr>
    <td width="100" >Username:</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="text-box" value="{{ username }}" placeholder="Username"/></td>                        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="align-left">Password:</td>
    <td><input type="password" class="text-box" value="" placeholder="Password"/></td>                        
</tr>                    
<tr>
    <td class="align-left"></td>
    forget-link"><a href="#" >Forget Your Passowrd?</a></td>                        
</tr>
```

views.py

```
def login(request):

    logout(request)
    username = password = ''
    if request.method :
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']     
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/main/')
    return render(request, 'index.html',{ 'username': username})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',      

    url(r'^login/', 'mysite.views.login', name='login'),
)
```

I have applied {% csrf_token %} after form tag in index.html.

When I click on Login button, I have the below error:

`CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`

Comment: on which url you are calling your login template. It that /login/ or any other ?

Comment: Did you add the middleware?

Comment: Yes, I added the middleware.

Comment: What version of Django?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using the tag {% csrf_token %} in your template but you had not generated the token previously in the view so the template doesn't know anything about it.

Following the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it) you have two options:

The first solution:

> Use RequestContext, which always uses
>   'django.core.context_processors.csrf' (no matter what your
>   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting). If you are using generic views
>   or contrib apps, you are covered already, since these apps use
>   RequestContext throughout.

So you have to change the code in your view like this:

```
def login(request):
    logout(request)
    username = password = ''
    if request.method :
        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/main/')

    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request,{ 'username': username})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

The second solution:

> Manually import and use the processor to generate the CSRF token and
>   add it to the template context. e.g.:

And your code should be (as mcniac told you):

```
def login(request):
    logout(request)
    username = password = ''
    if request.method :
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']     
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/main/')
    context = { 'username': username}
    context.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, 'index.html',)
```

Comment: Have you closed correctly the </table> and </form> tags in your template?

You can also try to use the HttpResponse instead of just render

Comment: Yes, I have closed all the tags. I have also applied HttpResponse. Even thought error is not solved :(

Comment: I've tested with your code and it's working for me :(

If you're using Django 1.5+ just make this change on your template and try :)

<form action="{% url "login" %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

Comment: I am using django 1.4. I have a pop-up box for login. Which is in index.html

Comment: try to catch the CSRF token in the request context, as the piece of code I wrote

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to apply the csrf to your context, your view would endout like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def login(request):

    logout(request) # not sure what this function is, I guess must be on some part of your code
    if request.method == "POST" :
        username = request.POST['username'] or ''
        password = request.POST['password'] or ''
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/main/')
    context = { 'username': username, }
    context.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: sorry for the half comment, now you see what I meant

Comment: you wouldn't need that if you were using a django form

Comment: I have applied context as you said, but still getting the same error. In backend, I have like:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py:55: UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.
  warnings.warn("A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.")

Comment: how do you submit the form?